# Read/write blob data in chunks with Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stream, blob

Is there a way to read and write from a `blob` in chunks using `Hibernate`. 
Right now I am getting `OutOfmemoryException` because the whole blob data is loaded in memory into a `byte[]`.

To be more specific, let's say I want to save a large file into a database table called `File`.

```
public class File {
   private byte[] data;
}
```

I open the file in a FileInputStream and then what? 
How do I tell Hibernate that I need to stream the content and will not give the whole `byte[]` array at once?
Should I use `Blob` instead of `byte[]`? Anyway how can I stream the content?

Regarding reading, is there a way I can tell hibernate that (besides the lazy loading it does) I need the blob to be loaded in chunks, so when I retrieve my `File` it should not give me `OutOfMemoryException`.

I am using:

- Oracle 11.2.0.3.0
- Hibernate 4.2.3 Final
- Oracle Driver 11.2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If going the Blob route, have you tried using Hibernate's `LobHelper` [createBlob](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/LobHelper.html#createBlob%28java.io.InputStream,%20long%29) method, which takes an `InputStream`? To create a Blob and persist to the database, you would supply the FileInputStream object and the number of bytes.

Your File bean/entity class could map the Blob like this (using JPA annotations):

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "DATA")
private Blob data;

// Getter and setter
```

And the business logic/data access class could create the Blob for your bean/entity object like this, taking care not to close the input stream before persisting to the database:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
Blob data = getSession().getLobHelper().createBlob(fis, file.length());
fileEntity.setData(data);
// Persist file entity object to database
```

To go the other way and read the Blob from the database as a stream in chunks, you could call the Blob's [getBinaryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBinaryStream--) method, giving you the InputStream and allowing you to set the buffer size later if needed:

```
InputStream is = fileEntity.getData().getBinaryStream();
```

Struts 2 [has a convenient configuration available that can set the InputStream result's buffer size](https://struts.apache.org/docs/stream-result.html).

Comment: How can I define @Lob in hbm.xml (we define our domain objects in hbm.xml files)?

Comment: I believe @Lob annotation is optional so long as you state it is type="blob"

Comment: Who is going to close that stream?

Comment: I *believe* Hibernate closes the Blob's stream after the insert is done. Hibernate uses its internal [BlobProxy](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/BlobProxy.java) class. If you debug and step through the code, you can observe the proxy blob's input stream eventually gets a closed value of `true` (right after the insert is done).But it's probably good practice to close the stream yourself after the session is flushed/transaction completed, since it is not defined in the contract for the `LobHelper` interface.

Comment: @RoySix Do you know if the Blob object has all the content inside it and streams back to client code or does it stream from the database?